# Prevent access to a given URL if accessed from particular page

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a grails URL as following:

`http://myspecialproject/MyApp/MyController/paymentSuccess`

The user should only go to the above URL if the previous page was `PayThroughCreditCard`.

At the moment, anyone who has the above URL can click and view the page.

How can I prevent this from happening?

I use grails security but that's to prevent unauthorized users accessing it.

Comment: Did you look into http://projects.spring.io/spring-webflow/ or  http://grails.org/plugin/webflow. I believe they should help you accomplish this. This should help too : http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Plug-ins/web%20flow.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`Grails filter`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters) to achieve that goal. In the before action you test where the request comes from and if it does not come from a valid URL you simply redirect the browser to a "Sorry you are not allowed to see this page" page.

```
paymentSuccessFilter(controller:'myController', action:'paymentSuccess') {
    before = { 
        if (! request.getHeader("referer").contains('controllerName')) {
          redirect(action: 'invalidAccess')
          return false
        }
    }
}
```

The checking logic is an aspect that should not be part of the target controller action itself. That's why you rather want to use an Grails filter to achieve your goal.

Comment: What should i have in `Does not meet your url` ? What is the condition ?. The condition i want to have is, that the User came from the `PayThroughCreditCard `page. How can i write the condition ?

Comment: so before filter is running it just before triggering that action - you can define controller/action like this if ((controllerName.equals('auth'))&&(actionName.equals('signOut'))) {

Comment: You should read the referer header. By using a filter your controller action is save but the checking aspect is outsourced from your controller action. The checking logic is an aspect that should not be part of the target controller action itself.

Answer (score 1):

you can also inspect referrer

```
def referrer=request.getHeader('referer')
```